# "Like this" or "this way". Any of them make sense in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

In a hypothetical situation in which someone is asking his or her father to never come home drunk again, any of the following sentences would make sense:

Please, daddy, promise you'll never come home **like this** again.

Please, daddy, promise you'll never come home **this way** again.

Comment: Note that one typically uses *any* when discussing three or more of a thing. When there are precisely two, we use *either*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Like this" is better, as in the context of "come home", "this way" would seem to refer to a route, rather than the state of being drunk.

But since it is the language of a young child, imprecise or unclear language might be used. So both "make sense".

Comment: Out in the gloomy night, sadly I roam,
I have no mother, no pleasant home;
nobody cares for me, no one would cry
even if poor little Bessie should die.
Barefoot and tired, I’ve wander’d all day
asking for work but I’m too small they say;
On the damp ground I must now lay my head
“Father’s a drunkard, and mother is dead!”

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this beautiful and sad lyric to me. I found the full version. An interesting thing is that in all the versions I found it says "Barefoot and tir'd, I've wandered all day" but in the lyrics found in the original score, which I also found, it says "Weary and tir'd , I've been wandering all day". Thank you again.